# Group map elements and sum their values in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, sum

I read the below data from a CSV file.

```
Pedro|groceries|apple|1.42 
Nitin|tobacco|cigarettes|15.00 
Susie|groceries|cereal|5.50 
Susie|groceries|milk|4.75 
Susie|tobacco|cigarettes|15.00 
Susie|fuel|gasoline|44.90 
Pedro|fuel|propane|9.60
```

I wanted to group the expenses of each customer like

Expense of Pedro:

Groceries - 1.42
fuel - 9.62

I also wanted to group the sum of the expense for each customer like

Total expense for each customer is:

Pedro - (1.42 + 9.60)
Nitin - 15.00
Susie - (5.50 + 4.75 + 15.00 + 44.90)

Can someone help me in how will I group the elements and sum their values.

I am able to read the file and print separate values. I mapped each group member with their expenses. But don't know how to sum up their values

can Someone help me?

This is my code, im sure this is incorrect

```
static String[] inputArray ;


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    groceryReport gr = new groceryReport();

    try {
        gr.readFile();
        System.out.println(gr.customerPurchase(inputArray).toString());
        }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("null")
private void readFile() throws IOException {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\....\\grocery.csv")); 
    String input= "";
    try{
        System.out.println("The total revenue for each customer is:");

    while((input = br.readLine()) != null )
    {
    inputArray= input.split("\\|");
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}



    public String customerPurchase(String[] inputArray){

    String sum = "" ; float sum1=0; float sum2 = 0;
    ArrayList<String[]> alist = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    alist.add(inputArray);
    String value = "";
    System.out.println(alist);
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    map.put(inputArray[0], inputArray[3]);
    System.out.println(map.get(inputArray));
    Iterator ite = map.entrySet().iterator();

    while (ite.equals("Susie"))
        ite.next();
        value = map.get("Susie");

            sum = sum+ value;


            return sum;


}
```

Comment: What's the specific issue? Seems simple enough.

Comment: You forgot to add your code...

Comment: Do you just want the total for each of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution can be found [here](http://www.nomorepasting.com/getpaste.php?pasteid=39665), but I will give you a short breakdown of it.

First of all I created a class names `Purchase` as an abstraction for each of the lines in your csv file. This is just a simple class to group together the information around a purchase (item type, specific item and price).

The `createReport` method takes the csv lines as input, and will return a datastructure a `Map<String, List<Purchase>`, the key to the map is going to be the names of the persons, and their associated purchases. If I wanted to fetch all purchases made by *Pedro* I would simply use `mapVariable.get("Pedro");` and it would return a `List<Purchases>` of all Pedro's purchases.

Finding the sum of Pedro's purchases is therefore a simple task, as can be seen in the `sum` method.

This ends up giving a report looking like this:

```
---------------------------------------
Name.                             Nitin
---------------------------------------
tobacco                            15.0
---------------------------------------
Total:                             15.0
---------------------------------------

---------------------------------------
Name.                             Pedro
---------------------------------------
groceries                          1.42
fuel                                9.6
---------------------------------------
Total:                            11.02
---------------------------------------

---------------------------------------
Name.                             Susie
---------------------------------------
groceries                           5.5
groceries                          4.75
tobacco                            15.0
fuel                               44.9
---------------------------------------
Total:                            70.15
---------------------------------------
```

Comment: This is terrific. Thank you so much for this. This was an interview coding question for me today, I'm a junior dev with QA automation experience. I have no clue how to go ahead with this.

Answer (score 0):

In object oriented languages, when you want to group specific pieces of data, this is accomplished by using classes.
Im assuming this is a homework assignment and so I can't give full details. But you want a person class that contains fields for the info you want. From there you can iimplemet methods to output exactly what you want?